# Is it possible to have two partitions on external drive that is used for time machine backups?

Tags: time-machine

Basically I want to create to partitions on the external SSD drive, one for backups using time machine and one for windows 10 that I will boot externally. Is something like this possible?

Comment: https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/i-want-back-up-multiple-macs-or-source-volumes-same-hard-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible.

The easiest way is to start with a clean drive (i.e. containing no data you want to save), and then use Disk Utility to [create two partitions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskutl14027/mac) on the drive. You can name the partitions so it is easy for you to identify which one is which.

The partition for Time Machine needs to be formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" (HFS+).

The Windows drive will usually be formatted during Windows installation.